# Tomcat thread pool? Commented out in tomcat.conf, should I use it?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, threadpool

I really don't consider myself a java or tomcat expert. I have a vps with tomcat running on it. In the tomcat.conf file there is the following.

Notice that the `Excecutor 'tomcatThreadPool'` and corresponding `Connector` referencing that `Executor` is commented out.

At the risk of sounding very stupid...I'm going to ask this question...

With the `Executor` and `Connector` commented out, how are my servlets functioning? In other words, are they using a default thread pool? Or should I uncomment the `Executor` and `Connector` for servlet efficiency?

I guess I'm not very knowledgeable in this area at all....

```
<!--
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" 
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
-->

<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
<!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
<!--
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
-->
```

Comment: This connector is commented out by default, [up to Tomcat 9](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/conf/server.xml#L74).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Tomcat documentation of Executor](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/executor.html) says (emphasis is mine):

> The Executor represents a thread pool that can be shared between
>   components in Tomcat. Historically there has been a thread pool per
>   connector created but this **allows you to share a thread pool**, between
>   (primarly) connector but also other components when those get
>   configured to support executors

So, you don't have to uncomment anything for Tomcat to work efficently, the Executor is for special needs as using more than one executor or using some thread pool yourself.

The referenced tomcat page is in the first results if you google "`Tomcat Executor`", by the way.

Comment: There are more setting you can config to use to fine tune the pool if use executor thread pooling.